# How can I update my local Forked Github project by a certain Pull request to main project?

Tags: git, github

I forked a certain project and cloned it to my PC. I find a pull request to main project that includes useful stuff for me. How can I update my fork and local copy with this certain pull request that is not presently merged with the main project?

I am a bit new in github therefore please aware that I mean proposed but not merged changes for main project  by "pull request".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your latest comment:

> Thanks for the attempt but this is not an exact answer to my question.
>   In my case I don't want to get latest updates of the upstream repo. I
>   just want to get updates of a certain commit that is not presently
>   merged by the main project

My answer is going to target a specific commit but since your original question mentions a pull request (which implies a branch) I will give a solution for that as well.

**How to pick up a single commit from a remote repo**

Assuming you have a local clone of the repo you forked if you type in the following you should get a single origin:

```
> git show remote
origin
```

Unless you've added the original's repo location, you won't have access to the commit you want to pick into your local one. So we need to add that, let's assume this repo is https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook.git. Notice this is an HTTPS clone URL because you won't have write access to this repo. Let's name it original_repo:

```
> git remote add original_repo https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook.git
```

And now let's get all the refs back:

```
> git fetch origina_repo
```

At this point you have all you need locally, you'll just need to merge the commit into one of your branches, let's assume your local master.

Find the commit you want to merge. This implies finding it in one of the branches the team used. Could be already merged to master or you could be picking it up from the branch that was used for the pull request. Either way, just run a series of `git log` to check what commit you want if you don't know the reference. When you do simply go to the branch where you want to merge the commit to and run:

```
> git cherry-pick COMMIT_ID
```

This will bring the commit to whatever branch you are at the moment.

**How to merge a branch from a remote repo**

The only difference in this steps is that instead of doing the cherry-pick you will be doing a merge. So imagine the contents of the pull request are in a branch named `so-pr`, you would simply do:

```
> git merge original_repo/so-pr
```

And that would merge the contents of `so-pr` into your working branch.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but this is not an exact answer to my question. In my case I don't want to get latest updates of the upstream repo. I just want to get updates of a certain commit that is not presently merged by the main project

Comment: I haven't try but this seems the answer to my question at least by definition. Thanks for you time :) Of course I'll check this out

Comment: If you bump into any syntax errors let me know, I'm 100% positive of the method though. Right answer but no upvote :me_sad